# Establecer valores por defecto para parametros de rutas en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando hacer una api rest para el paginado de una tabla de datos (pan de cada dia cuando en CRUD), pero quiero hacer que se puedan poner valores por defecto en los parametros que determinan la pagina actual y la cantidad de items a devolver en caso de no especificarlos por medio de la url, para darme a entender mejor mi ruta esta definida asi:

```
Route::get('banks/{page}/{per}', 'BankController@index');
```

Y mi controlador esta definido asi:

```
public function index($page = 1,$per = 5)
{
  $banks = bank::orderBy('id','DESC');
  $banks = $banks->paginate($per,['*'],'page',$page);
  return [
    'pagination' => [
      'total' => $banks->total(),
      'current_page'  => $banks->currentPage(),
      'per_page'      => $banks->perPage(),
      'last_page'     => $banks->lastPage(),
      'from'          => $banks->firstItem(),
      'to'            => $banks->lastItem(),
    ],
    'banks' => $banks
  ];
}
```

Quiero hacer que si no se define un 'per' se tome 5 como valor por defecto, y si no se define una 'page' ni tampoco un 'per'se tome 1 y 5 como valores por defecto respectivamente

Intente seguir la documentacion de Laravel pero no esta en mi idioma nativo y no entendi mucho el tema de hacer un middleware para los valores por defecto, al final intente haciendolo de la siguiente forma:

Ruta:

```
Route::get('banks/{page}/{per}', 'BankController@index')->middleware('defaults');
```

Kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'defaults' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SetDefaultLocalForUrls::class,
];
```

Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class SetDefaultLocaleForUrls
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        URL::defaults(['page' => '1']);
        URL::defaults(['per' => '5']);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Pero nada me funciona, en postman me salta el error de

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe algo exactamente como lo que buscas en Laravel, pero puedes usar los parámetros opcionales en la ruta, agregando un signo de interrogación al final de cada parámetro:

```
Route::get('banks/{page?}/{per?}', 'BankController@index');
```

De esta forma si solo escribes banks en la ruta, tomará los valores por defecto definidos en el método del controlador, y si ingresas solo un valor para page, per tomará el valor por defecto del método.

Comment: Gracias :0! me sirvio para {page?} pero no para {per?}, de todas maneras creo que con eso basta

Comment: Podrías también definir dos rutas distintas, según el caso